# shake / Vibrate a body in box2d?

Tags: iphone, box2d

How do you vibrate or cause a shake effect to a body of type static or dynamic or kinematic. I tried applying forces to a dynamic body in the timeStep, which did not work, as well I tried ApplyLinearImpulse many times a sec within the timeStep, which again did not give me the result. So right now Iam experimenting with adding a static circle body as a hinge point to my rectangular body and create a revolute joint between them. May be then applying a force could result in Tension between the 2 bodies? Does anybody know about this? have any ideas please let me know?

Comment: i'm not sure how it'll end up but you can also directly change fixtures position in every cycle a little.

Comment: how would I do that? I had tried repositioning body using setTransform to the left and right a few pixels, the timeStep is too fast the changes are not visible. How would I change fixtures position....just tried googlin.....please let me know thanks.

Comment: you can't directly change bodies positions, you have to change fixtures position, if you want to. `body->getFixture()` gives you access to body's first fixture, for the next fixtures call `fixture->nextfixture()`. and fixtures have setposition function that you can use to change their positions

Comment: I just googled to look for setPosition in b2Fixture class, there isn't any, but b2Body class has setPosition function. As well I tried this b2Fixture *f = body->GetFixureList(); f->setPosition()..setPosition did not come up...the IDE itself is not recognizing i.e in my xcode...still very confused...

Comment: @fiasal : after rechecking it I saw i was wrong, i used fixtures to change shape of already created objects, and used `body->setTransform` to change objects position.

Comment: Is the shake effect actually meant to be an influence on the physics simulation or are you looking for a cosmetic effect?

Comment: The point of a static body is that it does not move in response to forces; usually you set the position explicitly. If you're going to give impulses use a dynamic body; if you're going to set velocity, use a kinematic body.

Comment: yes I understand that...I have a kinematic body and wanted to achieve a shake effect while its at rest....

Answer (score 3):

okay I just figured everything out...all I had to do was to set the linearVeolcity using boolean logic. i.e

```
if(counter <50) 
{
 if(toggle)
  { 
    body->setLinearVelocity(5.0,0.0) 
  } 
 else 
  { 
    body->SetLinearVelocity(-5.0,0.0) 
  } 
  toggle = !toggle 
} 

counter++; 

if(counter>50) 
{ 
 break away from being static body 
}
```

all of the above code has to go in to the timeStep under the loop in which you iterate the b2Bodies of the world.....the logic is simple.